# using Autofac Webform with parameter constructor

Tags: c#, webforms, inversion-of-control, autofac

We have some legacy app assume that we can not change that SiteSettings class because complete project coding thousands of line will disturb. so we want to solve problem using DI. I created POC app here you can see in `global asax` there is comment   `//HOW CAN I PASS TenantId HERE so it will be same for this complete httprequest life.`

LegacyCode:

```
public class OrderController
    {
        public static string CompleteOrder()
        {
            return SiteSettings.Instance.DefaultTimeZone();
        }
    }


    public class SiteSettings
    {
        public ITenantSettings TenantSettings { get; set; }

        private static SiteSettings _instance;

        private SiteSettings() { }

        public static SiteSettings Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = new SiteSettings());

        public string DefaultTimeZone()
        {
            return TenantSettings.DefaultTimeZone();
        }
    }
```

New Classes for Injection

```
 public interface ITenantSettings
    {
        string DefaultTimeZone();
    }

    public class TenantSettings : ITenantSettings
    {
        private readonly int _tenantId;

        public TenantSettings(int tenantId)
        {
            _tenantId = tenantId;
        }

        public string DefaultTimeZone()
        {
            return "USA Time For Tenant ID " + _tenantId.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Global ASAX

```
public class Global : HttpApplication, IContainerProviderAccessor
    {
        // Provider that holds the application container.
        static IContainerProvider _containerProvider;

        // Instance property that will be used by Autofac HttpModules
        // to resolve and inject dependencies.
        public IContainerProvider ContainerProvider => _containerProvider;

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Build up your application container and register your dependencies.
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<TenantSettings>().As<ITenantSettings>().InstancePerRequest();

            _containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(builder.Build());
        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int id = 0;
            int.TryParse(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"], out id);

            var cpa = (IContainerProviderAccessor)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance;
            var cp = cpa.ContainerProvider;
            cp.RequestLifetime.InjectProperties(SiteSettings.Instance);
            //HOW CAN I PASS TENANTID HERE so it will be same for this complete httprequest life.
        }
    }
```

Default ASPX

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write(OrderController.CompleteOrder());
        }
    }
```

Error :

```
None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'CoreLibrary.Tenants.TenantSettings' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Int32 tenantId' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Int32)'.
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`WithParameter`](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/parameters.html), in this instance I would suggest the `ResolvedParameter`:

```cs
builder.RegisterType<TenantSettings>()
    .As<ITenantSettings>()
    .InstancePerRequest()
    .WithParameter(
        new ResolvedParameter(
            (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(int) && pi.Name == "tenantId",
            (pi, ctx) => int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"])));
```

In reality you will need something a little more resilient than `int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"])` but this gives you a flavour of a solution

---

#### Update

We need to remove the line `_instance ?? (_instance = new SiteSettings())` if we are to inject the dependencies. In my example `SiteSettings` now has a `static Initialise` method, and this method is the used to *construct* the value of `SiteSettings.Instance`.

Currently we are only interested in injecting `ITenantSettings` and as we want `ITenantSettings` to have a lesser lifetime scope (per request) than the scope of `SiteSettings` (singleton) we should inject a delegate (`Func<ITenantSettings>`).

```
public class SiteSettings 
{
    private static SiteSettings _instance;
    private Func<ITenantSettings> _tenantSettingsFactory;

    private SiteSettings(Func<ITenantSettings> tenantSettingsFactory)
    {
        _tenantSettingsFactory = tenantSettingsFactory;
    }

    public static void Initialise(Func<ITenantSettings> tenantSettingsFactory) 
    {
        _instance = new SiteSettings(tenantSettingsFactory);
    }

    public ITenantSettings TenantSettings { get { return _tenantSettingsFactory(); } }

    public static SiteSettings Instance
    {
        get {
            if (_instance == null) throw new InvalidOperationException();
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public string DefaultTimeZone() 
    {
        return TenantSettings.DefaultTimeZone();
    }
}
```

Here's a test that demonstrates what you are asking:

```
[Fact]
public void Demonstrate_TenantSettingsFactory_AlwaysResolvesCurrentTenantId()
{
    int tenantId = 0;

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<TenantSettings>()
        .As<ITenantSettings>()
        .WithParameter(
            new ResolvedParameter(
                (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(int) && pi.Name == "tenantId",
                (pi, ctx) => tenantId));


    var container = builder.Build();

    SiteSettings.Initialise(container.Resolve<ITenantSettings>);

    tenantId = 1;
    Assert.Equal("USA Time For Tenant ID 1", SiteSettings.Instance.DefaultTimeZone());
    tenantId = 2;
    Assert.Equal("USA Time For Tenant ID 2", SiteSettings.Instance.DefaultTimeZone());
}
```

Note I removed `InstancePerRequest` and `HttpContext.Current` as I am using a unit test project.

Comment: Is this code need to be placed Application_Start() if yes then HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"] should be diffrent for every request but if place this code in Application_BeginRequest() then I get error  public string DefaultTimeZone()
Line 26:         {
Line 27:             return TenantSettings.DefaultTimeZone();
Line 28:         }

Comment: The registration belongs in `Application_Start` and it will be resolved *per request*.

Comment: Dont you think since SiteSettings is singletone class so let say two user open page same time this can cause conflict in sitesettings load from querystring["tenantId"].

Comment: Each user request has it's own thread, it's own instance of `HttpContext.Current` and it's own instance of `ResolvedParameter`.

Comment: I undersatnd your point but if you see    OrderController    code   `return SiteSettings.Instance.DefaultTimeZone();` this calling single tone instance so isn't it conflict sitesettings if thread hit same time this instance.

Comment: Oh I see. `SiteSettings` as a *singleton* should not hold a reference to `TenantSettings`  as *per request*: this is known as a [captive depdendency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/)

Comment: so what minimum changes you think should be so we do not need to change much order controller class(because think about it as 1000 lines of other class codes too)

Comment: The simplest change would be to use a delegate in `SiteSettings`: `public Func<ITenantSettings> TenantSettingsFactory { get; set; }`

Comment: can you add new answer with complete class code and registration code.I am sorry I don't understand it ... bit newbie in DI

Comment: I still that this could create conflict if let say two thread parallel running and both calling inside SiteSettings.Instance.DefaultTimeZone() .... am I right?

Comment: No, you are wrong, the `delegate` calls into the `container` to resolve `ITenantSettings` and the `container` is thread safe.

Comment: I am sorry when I run this code I get this error [Click here to view image](http://i.imgur.com/hJQZvzI.png)

Comment: The error is caused by you having `.InstancePerRequest()` in the registration in conjunction with you running the code **not** as a web request. You have to have a web request and a `HttpContext.Current` to use `.InstancePerRequest()`

Comment: I don't understand its already coming from page load http://i.imgur.com/rpvOJ9T.png. can you update answer to use querystring to get tenantid?

Comment: How are you calling `Page_Load`?

Comment: as mention in question ... `Response.Write(OrderController.CompleteOrder());`

Comment: I mean are you going via some sort of URL from a browser?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89316/discussion-between-qujck-and-sof-user).